# React Native Select List Population

Tags: react-native

I am using this React Native package: https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form-native for display and capture form inputs.

And I got questions on display the select list based on custom API response.

```
{
    "response": {
    "countries": [
      {
        "PK_country_id": 132,
        "country_code": "MY",
        "country_name": "Malaysia"
      },
      {
        "PK_country_id": 196,
        "country_code": "SG",
        "country_name": "Singapore"
      },
      {
        "PK_country_id": 32,
        "country_code": "BN",
        "country_name": "Brunei"
      },
      {
        "PK_country_id": 36,
        "country_code": "KH",
        "country_name": "Cambodia"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Well, the documentation did mentioned populating the select list based on enums

```
const Country = t.enums({
  'IT': 'Italy',
  'US': 'United States'
}, 'Country');
```

Any guidance for transforming the custom API response into the enums format provided? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't understand. Transform `response. countries` to an object like `{
  'IT': 'Italy',
  'US': 'United States'
}`, then pass it to `t.enums`, it doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry but i'm still new to react-native. just wondering how i pass a function into t.enums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass function to `t.enums`. Just the result converted.

For example,

```
const res = {
    "response": {
    "countries": [
      {
        "PK_country_id": 132,
        "country_code": "MY",
        "country_name": "Malaysia"
      },
      {
        "PK_country_id": 196,
        "country_code": "SG",
        "country_name": "Singapore"
      },
      {
        "PK_country_id": 32,
        "country_code": "BN",
        "country_name": "Brunei"
      },
      {
        "PK_country_id": 36,
        "country_code": "KH",
        "country_name": "Cambodia"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

By this convert,

```
let convertedResult = res.response.countries.reduce(function ( result, current ) {
    result[ current.country_code ] = current.country_name;
    return result;
}, {});
```

You get

```
{
    'MY': 'Malaysia',
    'SG': 'Singapore',
    'BN': 'Brunei',
    'KH': 'Cambodia' 
}
```

Then pass this to `t.enums`

```
const Country = t.enums(convertedResult, 'Country');
```

Comment: do you mind explaining the code line syntax below?

const Country = t.enums(convertedResult, 'Country');

what is the difference between Country and 'Country'?

Comment: You can check [here](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-validation/blob/master/index.js) below line 87, that can tell you how `t.enums` works.